# Selenium Extraction Problems: Waits/Not Finding Elements

Tags: python, css, selenium, web-scraping

In both chrome and firefox, everything is fine up until I need to extract text. I get this error:

```
h3 = next(element for element in h3s if element.is_displayed())
StopIteration
```

I even added a fluent wait.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.voilanorbert.com/')
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("form-search-name")
inputElement.send_keys(leadslist[i][0])
inputElement = browser.find_element_by_id("form-search-domain")
inputElement.send_keys(leadslist[i][1])
searchbutton = browser.find_element_by_name("search")
searchbutton.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.results")))
wait2 = WebDriverWait(browser, 3000, poll_frequency=100, ignored_exceptions=[ElementNotVisibleException])
wait2.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.one")))
h3s = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('h3.one')
h3 = next(element for element in h3s if element.is_displayed())
result = h3.text
```

I think its because its not actually extracting anything, so its just an empty list.
Some pictures that will probably help:
This is the before picture:
[image]

This is the after picture:
[image]

**I need to extract what is in the "text-center displayed" class of the "result" class.**

[image]

Comment: You're looking for an H3 element but I don't see any in the HTML code. Please provide more details.

Comment: See new picture above.

Comment: I don't know Python, would it help you if I figured out a working C# solution?

Comment: doesn't have to be in python...as long as your solution doesn't contain functions that aren't in python. i should be able to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is fairly simple, you just need a different selector when waiting for the search result.
The approach below (C#) works perfectly, it'll reduce your code with a few lines.

One "result DIV" becomes visible when the search is done. It is the only element with the "text-center displayed" class, so that's all your selector needs.
Once such a DIV is displayed, you know where to pinpoint the H3 element (it's a child of said DIV).
So simply wait for the below element to become visible after you've clicked the search button:

```
        IWebElement headerResult = w.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("div[class=\"text-center displayed\"] h3")));
        string result = headerResult.Text;
```

Comment: Don't css selectors use "." notation? What are the brackets for

Comment: You're right, but the brackets also work (for any attribute) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp