# Selecting visible element via css selector or xpath

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

The XPath of the parent css selector (which is always visible) is as follows:

```
/html/body/section/div/div[2]
```

After 5 seconds or so (after some javascript), one of its children will be visible. I want to select this visible child via its xpath.

```
/html/body/section/div/div[2]/div[1]
/html/body/section/div/div[2]/div[2]
/html/body/section/div/div[2]/div[3]
/html/body/section/div/div[2]/div[4]
```

Then I want to get the element that has this xpath+(/h3)

In html they are like this:

```
<div class="results"><div class="text-center" id="result-error"><h3 class="one">
<div class="results"><div class="text-center" id="result-fail"><h3 class="one">
<div class="results"><div class="text-center" id="result-catchall"><h3 class="one">
<div class="results"><div class="text-center" id="result-success"><h3 class="one">
```

One of the four  above will be visible.

**EDIT**
Python equivalent of your code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)             
rslts=wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, (".results h3 .one")))
```

Yet I am getting this error:

```
rslts=wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, (".results h3 .one")))
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I am unsure of your css selector and the spaces in between. Looks like the presence_of_all_elements_located function is thinking there are 3 arguments instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Selenium Java binding.

```
// A generic selector to grab a list of intended elements
//This should return all four div you have mentioned in the question
By byCss = By.cssSelector(".results h3 .one");

//Make sure all the elements loaded properly
List<WebElement> elements = (new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(byCss));

for (WebElement element: elements){
    if (element.isDisplayed()){
        //do whatever you want with the element
        System.out.println(element.getText());
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually using Python but I understand Java...I don't want to click the element. I want to extract it(turn it into text). I need to grab the visible element's "one" class

Comment: if the visible h3 is the intended element then you can use `h3 .one` as cssSelector. See my edit

Comment: there are many elements (ones that I do not care about) with class one. So the CSSselector you defined won't work.

Comment: Please provide more html including the parent of the four children you mentioned then

Comment: The parent of the four children is just: <div class="results">

Comment: Edited. See if that's what you wanted

Comment: This line does not make sense: By byCss = By.cssSelector(".results h3 .one");

Comment: Maybe choose better variables, since the way that line is written its not very clear. Also please see the edit above.

Comment: @ohbrobig Can you explain *This line does not make sense:*? The selector is correct as per my knowledge. It will find all the child h3 containing the class one followed by any parent having class result. What am I missing?

Comment: I would ask for as much html as possible if you want me to fully test the selector

Comment: See this post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522924/selenium-extraction-problems-waits-not-finding-elements/29535674#29535674